# Error simple WebRTC chat on react.js and meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, meteor, webrtc

I'm trying to make a simple chat using `webrtc` technology, `react.js` and `meteor.js`.
This is client code:

```
 class Rtc extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
   }

   componentDidUpdate(){
     let localVideo, remoteVideo, peerConnection, localStream;
     $('#start').on('click', ()=>{ start(true) });
     let id = Meteor.uuid();
     localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');
     remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');

     if (!this.props.loadingRtc) {
       this.props.messagesRtc.forEach((item, i ,arr)=>{
         let signal = JSON.parse(item.text);
         if(i == 0)return;
         gotMessageFromServer(signal);
       });
     }

     if(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
       navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( { video:true, audio:true}).then( ( stream )=> {
         localStream = stream;
         localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
       }).catch(errorHandler);
     } else { alert('Your browser does not support getUserMedia API'); }

     function start(isCaller) {
       peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection( { 'iceServers': [{'urls': 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com'}, {'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},]});
       peerConnection.onicecandidate = ( e ) => {
         console.log('e.candidate', e.candidate);
         if(e.candidate != null) {
           Meteor.call('addMsgRtc', JSON.stringify({'ice': e.candidate, '_id':id}), id);
         }
       };

       peerConnection.onaddstream = ( e )=>{
         remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(e.stream);
       };
       peerConnection.addStream(localStream);
       if(isCaller) {
         peerConnection.createOffer().then(createdDescription).catch(errorHandler);
       }
     }

     function gotMessageFromServer(signal) {
       if(!peerConnection)  start(false);      
       if(signal._id == id) return;
       if(signal.sdp) {
         peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(signal.sdp)).then(()=> {
           if(signal.sdp.type == 'offer') {
             peerConnection.createAnswer().then(createdDescription).catch(errorHandler);
           }
         }).catch(errorHandler);
       } else if(signal.ice) {
         peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(signal.ice)).catch(errorHandler);
       }
     }
     function createdDescription(description) {
       peerConnection.setLocalDescription(description).then(()=> {
         Meteor.call('addMsgRtc', JSON.stringify({'sdp':peerConnection.localDescription, '_id':id}), id);
       }).catch(errorHandler);
     }
     function errorHandler(error) { console.log(error); }
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <video id="localVideo"  autoPlay muted style={{width:"40%"}}></video>
         <video id="remoteVideo" autoPlay       style={{width:"40%"}}></video>
         <br/>
         <input type="button" id="start" value="Start Video"/>
       </div>
     );
   }
 }


 export default createContainer( ()=> {
   const subscriptionRtc = Meteor.subscribe('rtc');
   const loadingRtc = !subscriptionRtc.ready();
   return {
     loadingRtc:loadingRtc,
     messagesRtc: msgRtc.find().fetch(),
   };
 }, App);
```

Server code:

```
export const msgRtc = new Mongo.Collection('rtc');
 let messagesRtc = [];
 let clients = [];

  Meteor.publish('rtc', function wsPub() {
    clients.push(this);
    _.each(messagesRtc, (message) => {
      this.added('rtc', message._id, message);
    });
    this.ready();
  });

 Meteor.methods({
    'addMsgRtc'(arr, id) {
      let newMessage = {_id:id, 'text':arr};
      messagesRtc.push(newMessage);
      _.each(clients, (client) => {
        client.added('rtc', id, newMessage);      
      });
    },
```

The problem is that why after the initialization of `getUserMedia` does not want to further this videos and what not so I can't understand. Because it is actually a similar code with the usual `websockets` [like this](https://github.com/shanet/WebRTC-Example/blob/master/client/webrtc.js) works and syncs fine.

UPD:
When you click on the button and call the function `start`.

> TypeError: Argument 1 of RTCPeerConnection.addStream is not an object

If `websockets` to put in then then it turns out another error:

Code:

```
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( { video:true, audio:true}).then( ( stream )=> {
    localStream = stream;
    localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  }).catch(errorHandler).then(()=>{
    if (!this.props.loadingRtc) {
      for(let i of this.props.messagesRtc){
        let signal = JSON.parse(i.text);
        gotMessageFromServer(signal)
      }
    }
  }).catch(errorHandler);
```

Error:

> DOMException [InvalidStateError: "Cannot set remote offer or answer in
>   current state have-remote-offer" code: 11 nsresult: 0x8053000b] 
>   app.js:11075:9 DOMException [InvalidStateError: "No outstanding offer"
>   code: 11 nsresult: 0x8053000b]

Comment: I don't understand. Are you not seeing local video, remote video, or neither? Any error messages?

Comment: When you click on the button and call the function `start`. `TypeError: Argument 1 of RTCPeerConnection.addStream is not an object`

Comment: I assume you're not seeing local video then since I gather `localStream` is `undefined`. Has the user given permission to share their camera? `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` won't complete until they do, and nothing in your code waits for it to complete, which means your success callback never runs and never sets `localStream`, so that's plausible.

Comment: I only see the local video and not see remote video

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Seems like a timing issue. The TypeError suggests `start` is being called before the `getUserMedia` success callback has run. Insert a couple of `console.log` statements to verify the order in which things happen. The way you've written it, local video must be visible on both ends before one side pushes the start button. Not the best approach imho.